# react-native-app-auth - Remember me flow in my App using Keycloak

Tags: react-native, authentication, keycloak

I'm trying to create a remember me flow in my App. I'm using the [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) library for login, using Keycloak to setup the login form in my App. I have the 'remember me' option enabled in the Keycloak admin panel. So, the **checkbox** button is shown in the login form. Now, what I need is **to put in the response** if the user selected or not the 'remember me' option.

I have this in the login theme to show the checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <#if login.rememberMe??>
            <input tabindex="3" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked> ${msg("rememberMe")}
        <#else>
            <input tabindex="3" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" type="checkbox"> ${msg("rememberMe")}
        </#if>
    </label>
</div>
```

So I would like to have the rememberMe attribute in the JWT access token, or maybe something like this in the response

```
{
   "refreshToken": "eyJh...",
   "accessToken": "eyJhbGci...",
   ...
   "rememberMe": true
}
```

Or, if there is a better way to remember the user credentials please let me know.

Note: the **Remember Me** option stores the value in a persistence cookie ([check here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#enabling-remember-me)), but I don't know how I can do what I need using the **react-native-app-auth library**